# Does Spring JPA Criteria always have single WHERE clause containing the combined conditions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, interceptor

I am using Spring JPA Criteria for all my Database interaction. As part of a requirement to append a dynamic native where clause to all the Database queries I used JPA Interceptor to append the dynamic condition in the overrided onPrepareStatement method like as shown below

```
@Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("person(\\w+_)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sql);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String alias = matcher.group(0);
            sql = sql.replace("where ",String.format("where %s.status=%d and ", alias, dynamicValue));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No alias found for the entity 'person'");
        }
        return sql;
    }
```

The above logic is working fine but since I am replacing `where` clause to append my native dynamic condition using `sql.replace("where ",` my biggest concern is will there be any situation like Spring JPA Criteria generates native sql with multiple `where` clause

Note: the above dynamic criteria (status=) is just for an example. Sometimes it can have many conditions to be appended based on some use case

Comment: SQL only allows one WHERE it is forbidden by the specification. That being said not sure if this is the best way to do this, you are probably better of using an Filter condition and let Hibernate handle it. Next to that what you are doing is dangerous as you now opened your code for SQL injection for malicious users.

Comment: Multiple where clauses would require a subselect, which is definitely possible. For dynamic filtering, maybe have a look at [`@Filter`](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-filter/) annotation

Comment: @M.Deinum The problem is that my dynamic where clause is a native criteria which I need to append because of which I cannot use Filter. Also regarding SQL injection, actually I am not getting this dynamic condition from API or any open networks but I am getting it from my another trusted database which we are managing. So do you think this has any issues of that sort

Comment: your replacement strategy is incorrect, consider following case: `where 1 = 1 or 1 = 2`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Actually my dynamic condition is a mandatory one

Comment: If you are munging SQL strings yourself you are always at risk, even that managed database can be compromised or filled with stuff by an angry employee. It won't happen, until it does. A filter condition is a native SQL. I would say if you can build the query you can also use the `Criteria` api to append things.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have 100's of API already have within the application. As per this requirement I was asked to append this native condition without any change in all other existing Criterias

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Since I have almost 100 API's where they are using Criteria extensively. Can we use Filter to append my dynamic condition without touching those implementation?

Comment: @AlexMan that does not make sense, your idea will not work for `where 1 = 2 or 1 = 1`. btw, you may inject some reliable **anchors** via `@Filter` and replace them in interceptor.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov how can we do that

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov you mean something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EQ9L.png

Comment: yeap, or `@FilterDef(name = "my_filter", defaultCondition = "{filter_anchor:{alias}}") @Filter(name = "my_filter", deduceAliasInjectionPoints = false)` to get better control over replacement process.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov but the problem is its not guaranteed which fields to be used on each situation. For example Sometimes for one use case I need to use `status='open'` , sometimes `active=false and type='assets'`, sometimes `firstName='Job'`. So how do I make this switching

Comment: yes, I see, that is why I suggested to inject non-sql fragment there. `{filter_anchor:{alias}}` will allow to find it and safely replace it knowing table alias.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251686/discussion-between-alex-man-and-andrey-b-panfilov).

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov `@FilterDef` and `@Filter` are not working with aggregative functions